# Strange Date Conversion 2014-16-02 08:00:00 AM ( yyyy-dd-mm)

Tags: php, date, datetime

So, i have this format date :

```
2014-16-02 08:00:00 PM
```

YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS AM/PM Format

```
Years - Days - Months
```

What is the best way to convert this to

```
2014-02-16 20:00:00
```

Without the AM/PM and with the month before the days.

I already tried it with the DateTime function from PHP :

```
//    $date = new \DateTime($row[0]);
//    $date_formatted = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

But this is not working because Datetime recognises the days as months because of this format YYYY-**DD**-MM

How to do this in PHP

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-d-m H:i:s A', '2014-16-02 08:00:00 PM');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Gives 2014-02-16 20:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks man, it's working!

Comment: You're welcome, bud! :)

Comment: 1) Why should OP *try this*?! 2)  "Hope this helps" and "Peace! xD" is pure noise and completely useless